# Javascript OR operator producing unexpected results

Tags: javascript

My problem is pretty self explanatory.

```
var data = {
   email: 'rick@james.drugs',
   alias: 'Rick'
};

var input = 'Rick';

// Want this to be false but is equating to true
console.log(data.email !== input || data.alias !== input);
```

Check out this example.

http://jsbin.com/lenixu/4/

Why is the OR operator failing to function here?

Comment: It works, reads as `console.log(true || false)`, so `true`.

Comment: You're saying *"is A or B true"*, which by definition, one or the other will be. Please describe in English what you're trying to figure out.

Comment: duh... Long day.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logical OR (|| operator) returns true if any of conditions on its sides is true. In your example data.email!==input returns true, so whole condition also returns true.

If you want this condition to return false if there is false on any of its sides you should use logical AND (&& operator).

Answer (score 2):

Looking at `data.email !== input`. Of course this would be true... 'rick@james.drugs' is not the same as 'Rick'`. Your "or" operator here is seeing if either of those statements are truthy. Once it finds a truthy statement it returns true regardless if any others are falsey.